# Run Time Error Android Studio - Because of Adding JAR

Tags: java, android, android-studio, jar

First off I want to apologize if my post isn't accurate or it has some harsh imagination with other posts I could use the solve the problem - been looking and haven't found.

So, I'm using Android Studio 2.1 Latest and most updated build.

So I have an app doing some very very basic stuff..
I work with sound and such, so I tried to use the following jars:

[First Jar](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjd-YTy0bvMAhUEIcAKHfOdDlkQFggaMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.java2s.com%2FCode%2FJar%2Fj%2FDownloadjavase10jar.htm&usg=AFQjCNGKZe9NBXcM8rMQlqmQrDKq1R1hHQ&sig2=oYV7zskb1KPXe5yHt6MXuA&bvm=bv.121070826,d.ZGg) | [Second Jar](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwi4gZSE0rvMAhVfF8AKHbU7ARgQFggaMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.java2s.com%2FCode%2FJar%2Ft%2FDownloadtritonusshare0371jar.htm&usg=AFQjCNG-XT8O81LQeARAR7FA1oQoCKNLOw&sig2=g-ONtnFxEnwpjyNa282cQg&bvm=bv.121070826,d.ZGg)

The things is, Before trying to work with the Jars, I can perfectly run my files and App works as expected.

When trying to extend App functionality by adding those 2 Jars (or just 1) and the relevant class code that uses those Jars, the App just won't start, it won't even load either on a device or the emulator. Important to mention - I've tried running the App with ONLY the jars (without new code) to isolate the problem and make sure the jars are the problem.

As much as I understand those Jars cause the problem, and Here's a Log of the error returned by the SDK :

```
Error:trouble processing "java/applet/Applet.class":
Error:Ill-advised or mistaken usage of a core class (java.* or javax.*)
Error:when not building a core library.
Error:This is often due to inadvertently including a core library file
Error:in your application's project, when using an IDE (such as
Error:Eclipse). If you are sure you're not intentionally defining a
Error:core class, then this is the most likely explanation of what's
Error:going on.
Error:However, you might actually be trying to define a class in a core
Error:namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example,
Error:from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most
Error:assuredly not work. At a minimum, it jeopardizes the
Error:compatibility of your app with future versions of the platform.
Error:It is also often of questionable legality.
Error:If you really intend to build a core library -- which is only
Error:appropriate as part of creating a full virtual machine
Error:distribution, as opposed to compiling an application -- then use
Error:the "--core-library" option to suppress this error message.
Error:If you go ahead and use "--core-library" but are in fact
Error:building an application, then be forewarned that your application
Error:will still fail to build or run, at some point. Please be
Error:prepared for angry customers who find, for example, that your
Error:application ceases to function once they upgrade their operating
Error:system. You will be to blame for this problem.
Error:If you are legitimately using some code that happens to be in a
Error:core package, then the easiest safe alternative you have is to
Error:repackage that code. That is, move the classes in question into
Error:your own package namespace. This means that they will never be in
Error:conflict with core system classes. JarJar is a tool that may help
Error:you in this endeavor. If you find that you cannot do this, then
Error:that is an indication that the path you are on will ultimately
Error:lead to pain, suffering, grief, and lamentation.
Error:1 error; aborting
:app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

After that error is  thrown the process is terminated and app won't even load / start running. If I delete the jar files and re-run the same code exactly - it works just fine.

Comment: Read the error message... "*you might actually be trying to define a class in a core namespace, the source of which you may have taken, for example, from a non-Android virtual machine project. This will most assuredly not work*"... tl;dr Android is not happy with the usage of a `java.*` or `javax.*` package

Answer (score 0):

it looks like the problem is with the Jars files. problem can be caused by inclusion of an older library or your IDE is misconfigured. check your dependencies depending on the android jars.
might have to go thought the files to troubleshoot the problem...